# CT W2 No state taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax, form-w-2

While getting a MS at the University of Connecticut, I did some lecturing thus earning some income and so I have a W-2 from the State of Connecticut. Since I have gone to file my taxes, I noticed there is no state taxes in "box 17" (it's empty yet "16" is not -- I did earn income). Is this in error or is it a special case since the W2 is from the state?

Comment: Did you live in CT the full year? Did you use a CT address when filling out your W4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box 17 is state income tax *withheld*.  It's quite possible that they withheld no tax for you.  Compare to the deductions on your paycheck if you're not sure.  If you can't do that for some reason, call the human resources (HR) department and ask.  Or a large organization might even have a separate payroll department that you could ask.